# deleting a row in datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

for a program that is being developed i want to delete some rows of a generated data table (named dtb). because the row amount can vary a (lastrow) variable have been defined as `integer = dtb.rows.count - 1`

theoretically the function should work with a table below; and lastrow should = 2 and delete the row with the value pear

0          apple

1          banana

2          pear

this is what has been tried `dtb.Rows(Lastrow).Delete()` but it does not actually delete a row from the data table after being performed any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Delete` on a `DataRow` does not necessarily remove it from the `Rows` collection of a `DataTable`. It generally won't and obviously shouldn't.

If the `RowState` property of the `DataRow` is `Added`, which will be the case for new rows, then calling `Delete` will actually remove the row. If the `RowState` property is `Unchanged` or `Modified`, the row will remain but the `RowState` is set to `Deleted`. The idea is that you then use a data adapter to save changes from the `DataTable` back to the database and rows with a `RowState` of `Added`, `Modified` or `Deleted` will be inserted, updated or deleted respectively.

After saving changes to the database, the `AcceptChanges` method is called. You can call it manually if you want but it is called implicitly by the `Update` method of a data adapter by default. When it's called, rows marked `Deleted` will be removed, so that is one option for you. Rows marked `Added` and `Modified` will be marked `Unchanged`.

```vb
With dtb.Rows(lastrow)
    .Delete()
    .AcceptChanges()
End With
```

If you're not actually using the `DataTable` as a local cache for a database then you should simply treate the `Rows` collection like any other collection. That means calling `Remove` or `RemoveAt` to remove an item. As you're using an index, `RemoveAt` would be the logical option:

```vb
dtb.Rows.RemoveAt(lastrow)
```

That will remove the row at that index from the collection, regardless of the `RowState`.

If you do want to mark a row `Deleted`. but still be able to find non-deleted rows by index then you have a number of options. The most obvious is to use the `DefaultView` instead of the `Rows` collection. That is a `DataView` and every item is a `DataRowView`. Previously deleted rows are not surfaced via the `DefaultView` by default and the `DataRowView` class has a `Delete` method that has the same effect:

```vb
dtb.DefaultView(lastrow).Delete()
```